# java synchronization and starvation

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

i have made a program and expecting output like this :

A
1
a
B
2
b
C
3
c
...

E
5
e

here is my code i think am getting starvation problem plz help me

```
class Product {
    static boolean flag1, flag2, flag3;

    synchronized void printLwrAlpha(char value) {
        // System.out.println(flag3+": inside lwr_alpha");
        if (!flag3)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        System.out.println(value);
        flag3 = false;
        flag1 = false;
        System.out.println("before notify");
        notify();
        System.out.println("after notify");
    }

    synchronized void printUprAlpha(char n) {
        // System.out.println(flag1+": inside upr_alpha");
        if (flag1)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        System.out.println(n);
        // System.out.println(num);
        flag1 = true;
        flag2 = true;
        notify();
    }

    synchronized void printNum(int num) {
        // System.out.println(flag2+": inside num");
        if (!flag2)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        // System.out.println(n);
        System.out.println(num);
        flag2 = false;
        flag3 = true;
        notify();
    }
}

class PrintNum implements Runnable {
    Product p;

    PrintNum(Product p) {
        this.p = p;
        new Thread(this, "Producer").start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            p.printNum(i);
    }
}

class PrintLwrAlpha implements Runnable {
    Product p;
    static char ch = 'a';

    PrintLwrAlpha(Product p) {
        this.p = p;
        new Thread(this, "Producer").start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            char c = (char) (ch + (i - 1));
            p.printLwrAlpha(c);
        }
    }

}

class PrintUprAlpha implements Runnable {
    Product p;
    static char ch = 'A';

    PrintUprAlpha(Product p) {
        this.p = p;
        new Thread(this, "Producer").start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            char c = (char) (ch + (i - 1));
            p.printUprAlpha(c);
        }
    }
}

public class MainClass1 {
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        Product p = new Product();
        new PrintNum(p);
        new PrintUprAlpha(p);
        new PrintLwrAlpha(p);
    }

}
```

i am getting this output:

run:
A
1
B
2
C
3
D
4
E
5
a
before notify
after notify

i think after this program is going in to starvation

Comment: Please properly indent your code before pasting (in eclipse, `Ctrl+Shift+F`

Comment: Whats the meaning of those flags?

Comment: First describe your goal. What should we help you with?

Comment: @Alexei Kaigorodov My goal is to print like this :A 1 a B 2 b C 3 c ...E 5 e

Comment: @user2833479 then do it in a single thread. Using multithreading to perform sequential tasks is a perversion, tell it straight your professor.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all your ifs, e.g.

```
if (!flag3)
```

with while loops

```
while (!flag3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem is that you're trying to use a single wait object with multiple threads. The common scenario for wait/notify is as follows: the one thread is waiting for resource to become available while the second thread produces the resource and notifies the first thread.
In code it may look like this:

```
class ResourceFactory {
     public synchronized void produce()
     {
         // make the resource available
         obj.notify();
     }

     public synchronized void consume()
     {
          if( /* resource is not available */ ) {
              obj.wait();
          }
          // do something with resource
     }
}
```

When multiple threads are trying to wait on a single object the problem is that it's up to implementation which thread would be awaken after notify call. I think you should make 3 different objects and do something like this:

```
// thread 1
obj1.wait();
obj2.notify()

// thread 2
obj2.wait();
obj3.notify()

// thread 3
obj3.wait();
obj1.notify()
```

Be careful and try not to deadlock your code.

And at last your code. First two threads are waiting and awaken each other despite the flags. And when the third thread is awaken there's no thread to notify it. So it's a classical deadlock.